# Export data into multiple sheet in same workbook using SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

We are trying to export some data from SQL server
into an excel sheet. The data records will be like
more than 1 lakh records. I noted that Excel has
a constraint of not creating rows more than 65,000.
In this case we need to create workbooks
in the multiple excel sheet.

Could you please help me how to creat multiple
workbooks thru SSIS in run time - if it is >65,000?

Comment: What is the purpose of exporting this data? No human can go through and make sense of 65,000 rows of data? If this is so you can export the data to another system, you should probably use a CSV file instead, which has no constraints like this.

Comment: @Mike Honey  Good Question. A Hundred Thousand is a "Lakh" in the South Asian Sub continent - Pak/India/Sri Lanka/Burma/Nepal/Bdesh

Answer (score 0):

If you still prefer all records to be in a single sheet, choose the destination as Microsoft Excel 2007 instead of Microsoft Excel 97-2003

[image]

If you require multiple sheets on the other hand, refer to Step:2 in the article below
http://danajaatcse.wordpress.com/2010/05/05/extracting-data-from-multiple-sheets-in-an-excel-file-in-ssis/